# Trigger using OPENJSON to add values to inserted records

Tags: sql-server

Azure SQL Server 2019 - I'm having trouble getting a Trigger to work correctly:

The table is called `dbo.MailArchive`.

The columns are:

```
Mail_Id
Mail_Sender
Mail_Received_DateTime
Mail_Subject
Mail_Body
Status
Successful_Actions_Count
Page_Load_Count
```

The data coming in to the database only has values for the the first 5 columns.  I need the Trigger to populate the other 3 columns.

Those last 3 columns are to be populated by parsing the `Mail_Body` field and separating the data out to the 3 columns.  The statement I'm using to return the records with this separation displayed is:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM dbo.MailArchive d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
   Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
   Request_Count int '$."Request count"',
) j
```

This returns the last 3 columns populated as we need.

But we need the record to actually be written that way, so I'm now trying to work this logic into a Trigger.  I want those last 3 columns to get populated as part of the INSERT of each incoming record.

This is what I've been working on:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BodyParseTrigger on dbo.MailArchive
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  INSERT INTO dbo.MailArchive (
    Status
    , Successful_Actions_Count
    , Page_Load_Count
  )
  SELECT 
    j.*
  FROM INSERTED
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
  WITH (
    Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
    Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
    Request_Count int '$."Request count"'
  ) j

  SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

When attempting to execute the creation of this Trigger, I get this error message:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I understand what the error is saying - it sees the `SELECT j.*` statement as one item, whereas the `INSERT INTO` statement contains 3 items.  But I can't figure out how to write the `SELECT j.*` section correctly so it works as required.

I tested this to see if it would work with just one item:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[BodyParseTrigger] on [dbo].[MailArchive]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  INSERT INTO dbo.MailArchive (
    Status
  )
  SELECT 
    j.*
  FROM INSERTED
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
  WITH (
    Status varchar(100) '$.Status'
  ) j

  SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

The Trigger successfully created this time, but, I get this error on any `INSERT` attempts:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ',' is found at position 246.

Would appreciate any help with the proper syntax for what I'm trying to accomplish.

**EDIT 1:**

Sample record as requested (only pertinent columns included):

Values coming into the Database:

```
Mail_Id   Mail_Body
1         Status: Completed
          Successful actions count: 106
          Page load count: 105

2         Status: Failed
          Successful actions count: 91
          Page load count: 90

3         Status: Completed
          Successful actions count: 44
          Page load count: 32
```

What the Record should look like after the Trigger:

```
Mail_Id    Mail_Body            Status      Successful_Actions_Count    Page_Load_Count

1          <same as above>      Completed   106                         105
2          <same as above>      Failed      91                          90
3          <same as above>      Completed   40                          44
```

Comment: We'd need to see some sample data which you are using in your `OPENJSON` statement to be able to help. I would suggest creating a [MRE] of just the query as at this stage the trigger is just additional complexity not related to the error.

Comment: Sample Data added to original post.

Comment: I have no idea why, but removing `CHAR(13)` from your code appears to work.

Comment: That’s odd. CHAR(13) is the line break, which seems to be mandatory for parsing the Body. I’ll take a look when I get back to my desk.

Comment: Dale, I removed `CHAR(13)` as a test and I got another JSON formatting error.  Can you be more specific as what you mean by "your code appears to work," when removing it?  You mean the Trigger accomplishes what I'm after?  If so, can you create an answer with what you've found to work?  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is likely going to be in the ANSI exact characters used in your stored data. I copy and pasted from you question, but that may not represent the exact control characters.

Comment: Have a play with this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f477f8dd8f979b5821064889ffab343 - this is a [MRE] i.e. a minimal representation of the problem. But for you to test it you will need to use the exact data as stored in your database.